# Mapping an Interface As A Primary Key Via Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

I have a class with it's own @Embeddable id class, let's call it ICompanyId. There are 2+ classes that implement ICompanyId. Classes that implement ICompanyId are the embedded id's for classes that implement ICompany (which there are 2+ implementing classes).

So, what I would like to do is this:

```
@EmbeddedId
public ICompanyId getId() { /* blah blah */ }
```

How do I tell Hibernate which implementing class to use? With a @ManyToOne or @OneToMany, all I would have to do is to specify a value in the targetEntity, but @EmbeddedId offers no such options. Can anyone help?

Jason

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried `@Target(CompanyIdImpl.class)` (see: [@Target](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html#d0e2890))?
Keep in mind that this is a Hibernate-specific solution.